# Defining an project internal lib folder in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-classpath

Is there any way to define a project lib folder relative to a Java Project? (an project internal lib folder). There are some options to define external or absolute path libraries. I can also add each jar, but I found no way to define a internal lib folder, so any jar I add in this folder is added to the classpath (like a web library)

I changed the .classpath file manually, but this classpath entry `<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib" />` doesn't create a lib folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.8"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
```

You can also create a User Library and set the library's directory to be in the workspace, but then you'll have to change the user library for every new jar you add.

Answer (score 1):

Classpath entries in Eclipse are (mostly..) absolute references. There is no built-in support for this feature.

I've found a few pages with how-to style references, but so far, only [one page](http://benjchristensen.com/2011/05/26/dynamic-directory-of-jar-files-in-classpath-via-eclipse-plugin/) that claims to have solved the problem.

Comment: Then, you'll have the same problem. You'll have to change the user library for every new jar you need to add.

Comment: Didn't work for me in Eclipse Kepler - the jar files in the selected folder are ignored.

Comment: @Rafael Shouldn't need to change the library, it's a directory, not a list of files.

Comment: Ah, my lib dir is both a native lib dir and a container built by the maven plugin. So it's working for me but not as a vanilla Eclipse feature.  Are you using maven or gradle? If you are, you'll see what I'm seeing.

Comment: Hi @PaulHicks. In Eclipse Luna there's no options for a relative directory.